# Find and delete many different strings in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, find-and-replace

I have two different tables on Excel, and I want to remove from the first table all the elements presents on the second table.

In the first table I have a long list (10000) of references, they are NOT 1 for each cell, there are cells with several reference and cells with only 1.

My idea was to go in the second table and take the references I have in the second table and do manually one by one the "find and replace" with an empty space, but is is very very long and I should do it 400 times. It is possible to do it automatically?

Comment: Do it manually once and record a macro.  Put the macro into a loop in VBA to iterate through the list.

Comment: #Gianni ,,, would you like to remove Text within the String or Whole record ??

Comment: Share sample data with us will help us to fix it in better way !

Answer (score 0):

**This UDF will help you to compare both Tables/Columns to find Common text and produce Revised Text.**

[image]

```
Function RemoveText(strInput As String, rngFind As Range) As String

Dim strTemp As String
Dim strFind As String

strTemp = strInput

For Each cell In rngFind
    strFind = cell.Value
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, strFind, "")
Next cell

RemoveText = strTemp

End Function
```

**How it works:**

1. Populate common text in `Column C`.
2. Write this Formula in Cell `D2` & Fill 
   down.

   ```
    =RemoveText(A2,$C$2:$C$3)
   ```

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Comment: Thanks @fixer1234,, this might `remove from the first table all the elements presents on the second table`, has confused me !

Comment: @fixer1234,, then better I just delete my post !

Comment: @fixer1234, now check I've revised my answer which I think is more appropriate to the OP.

Comment: I still read the question differently.  My impression is that the OP has a collection of "references" that are text strings.  Their 2nd table contains a list of the references they want to delete.   The 1st table contains records, where each record can contain one or more different references.  They want to find any examples of the 2nd table references in the 1st table, and delete them from the 1st table records.  (cont'd)

Comment: It's implied that any 2nd table reference could potentially occur in more than one record in the 1st table, and a 1st table record could potentially include more than one reference to be deleted.  When the process is complete, you can have records remaining that were unaffected, partially deleted, or left blank.  That's just my read of the requirement.  You might want to ask the OP to clarify whether this is correct.

Comment: @fixer1234,, thanks for the findings,, I've already written to the OP to  share sample data,,, and I do hope OP will return soon to make it clear,, ☺